# R Loop between two datatables

Tags: r, loops

Since it is hard for me to solve another puzzle posted on this site due to computation limits, I am trying something new as a substitute, which should work. I have two large datasets, one with monthly firm data, one with monthly bank data :

```
Data_firm <- data.frame(
  Firm = c("A", "A", "B"),
  time = c("1", "3", "2"),
  postal= c("20", "20", "67")
  )

Data_bank <- data.frame(
  Bank = c("AB", "AC","BD"),
  Postal_bank = c("20", "67","20"),
  entry = c("1","1","2"),
  exit = c("6","5","7"))
```

I would need to add a column with the number of banks present in the same department as the firm at each time, accounting for the fact that some banks enter and some do exit (entry, exit variables in "Databank"). In theory, I should have the fllowing column in the example above :

```
nbbankindepartment = c(1,2,1)
```

I have tried the following

```
for (row in 1:nrow(Data_firm){
dep <- Data_firm[row, "postal"]
time <- Data_firm[row, "time"]
count <- sum(Data_bank$Postal_bank == dep & Data_bank$entry <= time & Data_bank$exit > time, na.rm = TRUE)
Data_firm[row,"nbbankindepartment"]<-count
}
```

But I only get 0s as a result. Does anybody have a solution ? What I am not doing right ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I honestly don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @MartinGal sorry if it is not clear : I am trying to count the number of banks in the department (county?) of each firm at each time the firm appears in the first datatable and to add a column with the first data table with this number of banks. However I cannot join both tables because the results would be too big.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my best guess for your problem:

```r
library(dplyr)

Data_firm %>% 
  left_join(Data_bank, by = c("postal" = "Postal_bank")) %>% 
  filter(entry <= time, exit > time) %>% 
  group_by(Firm, time, postal) %>% 
  summarise(nb_bank_in_department = n(), .groups = "drop")
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  Firm  time  postal nb_bank_in_department
  <chr> <chr> <chr>                  <int>
1 A     1     20                         1
2 A     3     20                         2
3 B     2     67                         1
```

Comment: thank you for this answer that is actually what I tried initially but there are too many observations, i.e. the table resulting is too big.

Comment: What do you mean by _the table resulting is too big_? Does it take too long? Doesn't it fit into the memory? What problems occure?

Comment: Yes it is a memory issue (more than 50m rows). But I was writing when I saw your message I actually derived a solution from your solution. Instead of working at firm level, I worked at department level then cleaned the file for duplicates and merged it with the firm file and it works ! Thanks a lot !